# Selenium won't find element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My code works on the first expandable list, finds the element, but won't do it on next list below. I don't know why it would do so.

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("www.example.com")
time.sleep(2)
# Find the input element by its name
input_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "country")
time.sleep(2)
Input "Germany" into the element
input_element.send_keys("germany")
```

I tried find by id, Name and xpath, but didn't manage to get it to work.

Comment: Can you tell us the url of the page you're scraping?

Comment: Please provide url, expected output and actual output so that the issue can be reporduced and debugged.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus https://online.mfa.gov.ua/application

Comment: @NehalBirla i dont get any errors, its i want on this url the fields filled by selenium

Comment: YAVUZSATCAPAR, voted to **Leave Closed** (from the [Reopen Votes Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/33759015)), as "*this question has been answered, is not unique, and does not differentiate itself from another question*", notably, it's **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo** as also noted in Revision 2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this for the fields on your webpage

```
input_country = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "country")
input_country.send_keys("Австрія")
time.sleep(2)

input_consulate = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "consulate")
input_consulate.send_keys("ПУ в Австрії")
time.sleep(2)

input_category = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "category")
input_category.send_keys("Паспортні дії")
time.sleep(2)

input_service = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "service")
input_service.send_keys("Засвідчення заяви про шлюбну правоспроможність")
time.sleep(2)
```

Germany is not present as an option in the list of countries. You need to select only from the options present in the list. The next dropdown will not be active if you enter invalid data in the dropdown